# Can you select more than one time the power Magic?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-2e

I'm new in M&M and I'm starting to build a character that is focus on Magic. For what I read you can have an array of powers and this works perfectly with the power -Magic-. The downside of an array is that you can only use one element of the array at the same time (you cannot fly and shoot magic at the same time if both powers are in the array), thus, I am wondering, can you select more than one time the power Magic to be able to use/have active several magic powers at the same time (flight and fight, for example)?

For example having these Magic powers divided by (It is just an example, don't mind if the pp distribution is not optimized or useful):

- Movement Magic (10pp + 4pp for array): Teleportation, Flight, Astral
  Projection,  Dimensional travel, Burrowing.
- Protection Magic (10pp + 3pp): Immunity, Mind Shield, Regeneration,
  Sensory Shield.
- Attack Magic (30pp + 3): Hellfire, Shadow Control, Stun, Telekinesis.
- Utility Magic (8pp + 2): Dimensional Pocket, Mind read, create object.

The Gadgeteer example in the core book has multiple Gadgets, but I read that the GM might not allow that.

Comment: Where did you read about the Gadgeteer example, out of interest?

Comment: @Snoof I read it in the Core Book, second edition, page 19.

Comment: Ah. That is where the archetype is. Where did you hear the GM might not allow multiple gadgets?

Comment: @SeanDuggan In the Device description, page 82 it says "With the GM’s permission, you can split power points from this power into several devices, so long as they can all be taken away from you in the same manner.", thus I read it as it may not be possible unless the GM accept to do it. Did I read it wrong?

Comment: Ah. What they mean there is some thing like having five 1 pp Hard to Lose Devices (say a set of rings) for 4 pp.

Comment: Of course, I feel obliged to point out that the GM always has the final say on what's allowed, but the rules are in your favor here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, yes, they're all separately purchased Arrays, and it doesn't matter that they have the same name and descriptor of "magic". Other options for this situation include Dynamic Arrays (each dynamic array slot costs an additional power point, but when reconfiguring your array, you can select multiple Dynamic slots and use some or all of their ranks, as long as all slots so chosen add up to the total cost of the array), multiple powers in a slot, or Power Reserve (I think that's the name. It's in Ultimate Power and basically involves a dynamic array which can only be used to boost existing powers).